# Make the calendar web part static

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, web-part, sharepoint-calendar

I have a request to make the calendar web part static.

Not allow users to change the month or click back to the previous week.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it using CSS. Edit the calendar.aspx page and add the following CSS either using Content Editor webpart or Snippet/Script web part.

```
    /* Hides Left Nav Small Calendar, Left/Right Nav(arrow) and Ribbon Tab for changing Scope(Year, Month, Week) */
    div.ms-core-navigation #DatePickerDiv, 
    div.ms-acal-header a[id$="nav_prev_a"], 
    div.ms-acal-header a[id$="nav_next_a"], 
    li[id$="Calendar.Scope"] {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

Also, go to the list settings and change the default scope to 'WEEK'.

In addition to hiding using the CSS, use the jQuery code as suggested by Jussi.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward water-proof way of doing that, but I'd use jQuery to clear the required HREFs and ONCLICKs.

So something like:

```
// Disable small month table navigation
$("#DatePickerDiv a").attr("href", "#");
$("td[class^='ms-picker']").removeAttr("onclick");

// Remove month/week navigation
$("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView a[id$='nav_prev_a']").remove();
$("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView a[id$='nav_next_a']").remove();
```